# Database structures Phpadmin in MySQL CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Imagine we have a phpadmin database and we have a table for students and student_music and student_friend student_friend_music. Does this make sense performance wise to have four tables? or do you think we  need to have three tables for students students_friends student_music and table for music. How does facebook stores friends relationship in it's database?

Other thing is that I designed the data base for both. I don't know if I see any difference but I think once the users increase one would beat other performance wise?

So my question concerns the performances of querying:
Is this better to have more tables or 
Can we have duplicates.

Do you know any good book, tutorial or reference I can study to know about relational data bases in Php my admin and mysql.

Update:
Table Student can have many to many relation with itself. 
Table Music has Many to Many with the student as well.

```
Student id Student_friend  Music id     STUDENT_MUSIC     
  A      1      1-3         YT    1          1  3
  B      2      2-3         RU    2          2  3
  C      3                  PI    3          3  1
                                             3  2
```

So I am using something called Data Mapper in code igniter which causing me a headache but this sounds like a structure I am thinking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/) for a mysql introduction and the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) article on relational databases.  Read about tables, primary and foreign keys.  Before worrying about performance you need to address the structure of your database.

Try ([One-to-Many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=association.php):A student can own many pieces of music and have one friend):

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    friend_id INT)

CREATE TABLE Music(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    music_title VARCHAR(30),
    music_student_id INT)
    FOREIGN KEY (music_student_id) REFERENCES Student(id)
                  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Or Try ([Many-to-Many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php):Many students can own many pieces of music and have many friends):

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30))
    FOREIGN KEY (id) 
    REFERENCES StudentMusic (Student_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE Music(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    music_title VARCHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) 
    REFERENCES StudentMusic (Music_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE StudentMusic (
    Student_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Music_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY  (Student_id,Music_id)

CREATE TABLE Friendships(
    student_A_id INT,
    student_B_id INT)
    PRIMARY KEY  (student_A_id,student_B_id)
```

Handling the data views of the relationships can be shown using a Select statement. In the One-to-Many design finding a Student's music uses the following query:

```
Select Student.first_name,Student.last_name,Music.music_title 
FROM Student 
LEFT JOIN Music on (Student.ID=Music.music_student_id)
```

Part of designing a database is figuring out what relationships you will need to query.

Also look into [normalizing databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: you are right I should not be worried about performance but I am kinda of serious about writing code. I should choose the best solution.

Comment: Being serious is fine but you usually choose an extensible design until you need more performance.

Answer (score 3):

table suggestions:

table_students (contains students info, etc)
table_music (music pref of studs with student id from table_students)
table_friends (contains student id's from table students and flag value either friend or not friend)

Comment: yeah it is true...but My question is rather: Does it make sense to design a database and have duplicate entries in various tables. or should we add more relations to avoid duplicate entries. I will edit my post above with an example.

Comment: i suggest add more relations.

Comment: I am not sure if you worked with datamapper but It is sort of limiting me now. It makes the whole MySql object oriented. So right now I can't figure out how to set self relationships many to many with it self. I wish I could just write MySql without bounding myself into a frame work like Code igniter.